# React async element

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I'm struggling with a component in which I fetch data from an API.

the thing is I want to return a img element which src is a property of the object i fetched and stored in a state:

```
export default function Prediction(){
const [groupMatches, setGroupMatches] = useState([]);
const groups = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"];
const [teams, setTeams] = useState([]);
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMatches = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          headers: { "X-Auth-Token": `${apiToken}` },
        });

        const json = await response.json();

        setMatches(await json);

        setGroupMatches(
          await json.matches.filter((matches) => matches.stage === stage[0])
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchMatches();

    const fetchTeams = async () => {
      try {
        const response2 = await fetch(
          "https://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/WC/teams",
          {
            headers: { "X-Auth-Token": `${apiToken}` },
          }
        );
        const json2 = await response2.json();
        setTeams(await json2);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    };
    fetchTeams();
  }, []);

function carrouselElement(group) {
    const groupX = groupMatches.filter(
      (matches) => matches.group === "GROUP_" + `${group}`
    );

    return (
      teams &&
      groupX.map((match, i) => (
        <li key={match.id} className="matches">
          <img
            className="home-img"
            src={`${
              teams.teams.filter((team) => team.id === match.homeTeam.id)[0]
                .crestUrl
            }`}
          />)

return groups.map((group) => (
    <div>
      <ul>{() => carrouselElement(group)}</ul>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Enviar</button>
    </div>
  ));
}
```

The problem is an async one I think, but idk how to figure it out... Cant render the img

Comment: Please provide additional details to your code. state, your side effect that calls your fetched data from the API.

Comment: What do the `response` and `response2` objects look like?

Comment: @AndrewHulterstrom what kind of info of the objects do you need?

Comment: I just suggest you console.log those objects and verify they look how you expect